# Doctrine saves entities twice

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Iam using Symfony(4.3) and Doctrine. When I want to get a user like this in the constructor of the script:

```
$userRepo = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
    $this->systemUser = $userRepo->findOneBy([
        "firstName" => "system",
        "lastName" => "system",
    ]);
```

And save the reference to this user for example at a `createdBy`-field like this:

```
$newUser->setName("test");
$newUser->setCreatedBy($this->systemUser);
$this->entityManager->persist($newUser);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

The `systemUser` is persisted to the database after every `flush()`.

I already tried to get only the reference with

```
$this->systemUser = $this->entityManager->getReference(User::class, $this->systemUser->getId());
```

But this doesn't work either.

Edit:
The `setCreatedBy`-Method:

```
public function setCreatedBy(User $user): void {
    $this->createdBy = $user;
}
```

The 'createdBy'-Field:

```
/**
* @var User
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
*/
protected $createdBy;
```

Comment: So whenever you add a relation it doesn't re-use the id / foreign key of the intended inverse-side but persists a new instance and sets the relation to that one? What is inside the `setCreatedBy` method? Add it to the question please, together with the doctrine mapping for the "created_by" property expected to store the user/relation afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the `cascade={"persist"}` option for the relation which means Doctrine will save "new" entities found through the relation.

As your question suggests the `createdBy` field can only contain a relationship to already existing users. This means `cascade` is definitely not necessary here. It's also the reason why existing entities are persisted again in your case.

Remove the `cascade` option from the mapping-configuration for the property to resolve your issue.

Clear your cache afterwards.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. After doing it like you said, I get this error: `Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:  A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\User#createdBy' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\User@000000007c9234cb000000005adf38f2`

Comment: Is this a bi-directional relationship? Did you i.e. add a property like `usersCreated`?

Comment: Try `$em->entityManager->merge($newUser);` please. Are you calling `$this->entityManager->clear()` or `$this->entityManager->detach($user)`  somewhere? Did you define multiple entity-managers?

Comment: When I use `$em->entityManager->merge($newUser);` all the sub-entities from the `$newUser`-Object are not persisted in the database. When using `persist()` doctrine wants to create the subentities correctly but it fails with the error mentioned above. In german: Bin grade mit meinem Latein am Ende..

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: 
I forgot to mention that I insert ~ 70.000 items in a loop and use `clear()` every 100 rows. The problem is the use of the entity manager's `clear()`-method. it detaches all doctrine-managed entites so doctrine thinks that these entities are new and saves them to the db. So I have to do it like this:

```
$newUser->setCreatedBy($this->em->getReference(User::class, $this->systemUser->getId()));
```

Comment: you should know, that I read the selected answer and thought "no, that wouldn't solve the problem". In fact, your answer is correct, since it mentions the relevant part omitted from the problem description and provides an answer that actually fits.