# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: {field_name}

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine, phpunit, entitymanager, symfony5

While upgrading Doctrine to 2.8 and phpunit to 9.5 I got issue in my unit tests:
My code like:

```
$category = new Category();
$category->setName('My new category');
$this->entityManager->persist($category);
$this->entityManager->flush();

$document = new Document();
$document->setName('My new document');
$document->setCategory($category);
$this->entityManager->persist($document);
$this->entityManager->flush();

$document = $this->service->findByName('My new document');
$document->setAuthor('Some person');
$this->entityManager->persist($document);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

And in the last flush I have error:
`Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: category.name`

Perhaps something wrong in model, I added cascade={'persist'} because of previous issue with it, Phpunit proposed me to add it

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $categories;
```

Also, my category setter:

```
    /**
     * @param Category $category
     *
     * @return Document
     */
    public function addAddOn(Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }
```

Before updating libraries it works fine. I debugged test and found that Entity Manager in last flush tries to flush every previous flushes from code, and it crushes on unique fields.
I tried to use `$this->entityManager->clear();` and `$this->entityManager->refresh();` for all items but it didn't help.

Comment: So, I tried to find why EntityManager processed flushes twice but didn't find any, as my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine saves entities twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671162/doctrine-saves-entities-twice)